# How to check if the previous build on the same branch has started <3 hrs or >3 hrs using Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a MultiBranch Pipeline set up to trigger the pipeline on Git merge on specific branch in Jenkins, where I wanted to have a condition to check if the previous build on the same branch has started before <3 hrs elso >3 hrs to abort the job.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as like below, this should work for your requirement.

```
   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
    pipeline {
        agent any
        stages {
            stage ("TestStage"){
                steps {
                    script {
                        def previousBuildStartTime = currentBuild.rawBuild.previousBuild.timestamp
                        def previousBuildStartTime_1 = previousBuildStartTime.getTimeInMillis()
                        def currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                        def duration = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(currentTime - previousBuildStartTime_1)
                        echo "${currentTime} and ${previousBuildStartTime_1} and ${duration}"
                        catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'ABORTED'){
                            if (duration < 3 || duration > 3){
                                echo "Less than 3 or greter than 3"
                                error("Aborting the stage")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

you need to approve below signature in Jenkins in-process script approval to make it work.

```
method hudson.model.Run getPreviousBuild
method hudson.model.Run getTimestamp
method java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit toHours long
method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper getRawBuild
staticField java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit MILLISECONDS
```